# mutating method sent to immutable object, only happens on physical device

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, unrecognized-selector

I've tried everything I can think of, and all of the suggestions given to fix this error. The app runs fine on the iOS simulator, but it crashes on a physical device (my iPhone 5).

Here is the error I get:

```
2015-01-23 16:26:43.232 Kyle's App[2343:773183] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

The declaration of the properties of this class are:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSUserDefaults *defaults;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *classes;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *foundClasses;
```

all of these are initialized as mutable objects, except for the user defaults
and the method where the error occurs:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     NSMutableArray *notes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.classes[indexPath.row][@"notes"]];
     [notes addObject:[[self.defaults objectForKey:@"New Note"] mutableCopy]];

     self.classes[indexPath.row][@"notes"] = [notes mutableCopy];//problem

     [self.defaults setObject:@(indexPath.row) forKey:@"Current Class"];

     [self.defaults setObject:self.classes forKey:@"Classes"];
     [self.defaults setObject:[self.defaults objectForKey:@"New Note"] forKey:@"Current Note"];
     [self.defaults setObject:@YES forKey:@"Created New Note"];
     [self.defaults synchronize];

     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Show Summary" sender:self];
}
```

The line that produces the error is `self.classes[indexPath.row][@"notes"] = [notes mutableCopy];//problem`

All help is much appreciated, and I apologize if anything is wrong, as this is my first time posting on StackOverflow. If you need any more info, please let me know.

Thanks.

UPDATE- I have the code where the dictionary is initialized, and I'm not sure how it is still immutable.

```
[self.classes addObject:(NSMutableDictionary *)@{
                              @"title": textField.text,
                              @"notes": [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]//(NSMutableArray *)@[]
                              }];
```

Comment: Where's the code where you put the dictionaries in `self.classes`? You need to be sure you are adding `NSMutableDictionary` and not `NSDictionary`.

Comment: your 'notes' array is mutable array, so method 'mutableCopy' is unnecessary

Comment: Try this `self.classes[indexPath.row][@"notes"] = [notes copy];`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put a mutable version (NSMutableDictionary, NSCache etc.) of `NSDictionary` into your array `classes`.

```
[self.classes addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];
```

---

**EDIT**: It is not the right way to convert an immutable object to its mutable equivalent. You should call `[mutableCopy]` instead of casting.

```
[self.classes addObject:[@{
                          @"title": textField.text,
                          @"notes": [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]} mutableCopy]];
```

Comment: I tried to type cast the object, which I posted above I'm still getting the error though. Any suggestions?

Comment: How should I cast the objects to make them mutable @ozgurv ?

Comment: @kasandell you can send `[object mutableCopy]` message to the receiver.

Comment: where should I put that message exactly? I'm a little confused.

Comment: Also @ozgurv do you have any idea why this runs on the simulated devices but not my real device? Are there any known reasons that this happens?

Comment: @kasandell I've updated my answer with respect to your update.